# Subtract Two Columns defined as Ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where the user imports text files to the excel workbook. From there we want calculations to be completed automatically. I am working on the calculation of subtracting the current data from the initial. Please see image where the blue outlined boxes are the current data (amount of current data is dynamic, depends on how many text files the user imports). So I want to subtract blue columns from the red column. [image]

And I want the values from the calculations to be printed on a separate sheet titled "Calculations1" but so far when I run the code in my column where the values should go it prints #NAME? like the image shown below. 
[image]

Here is my code

```
Sub Calculations1()

Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim hiddenws As Worksheet
Dim calcws As Worksheet
Dim iRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng4 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range
Dim Rng6 As Range
Dim NewRng1 As Range
Dim NewRng2 As Range

A = Worksheets("Information Sheet").Range("E12").Value
B = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B2").Value

Set calcws = Worksheets("Calculations1")
Set hiddenws = Worksheets("Hidden 2")
Set iRng = hiddenws.Range(hiddenws.Cells(1, 1), hiddenws.Cells(1, hiddenws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

For i = 1 To B
If i <> B Then
    For Each cel In iRng
        If cel.Value = "A0_ " & i Then
        With hiddenws
            Set Rng1 = cel.EntireColumn.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            Debug.Print Rng1.FormulaR1C1
            Set Rng2 = hiddenws.Cells(Rng1.Row - 1, Rng1.Column)
            Debug.Print Rng2.FormulaR1C1
            Set Rng3 = Cells(cel.Row + 1, cel.Column)
            Debug.Print Rng3.FormulaR1C1
        End With
        End If

        If cel.Value = "A0_ " & A Then
        With hiddenws
            Set Rng4 = cel.EntireColumn.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            Debug.Print Rng4.FormulaR1C1
            Set Rng5 = hiddenws.Cells(Rng4.Row - 1, Rng4.Column)
            Debug.Print Rng5.FormulaR1C1
            Set Rng6 = Cells(cel.Row + 1, cel.Column)
            Debug.Print Rng6.FormulaR1C1
        End With
        End If
    Next cel

    With hiddenws
    Set NewRng1 = .Range(Rng3.Address & ":" & Rng2.Address)
    Debug.Print NewRng1.Address
    Set NewRng2 = .Range(Rng6.Address & ":" & Rng5.Address)
    Debug.Print NewRng2.Address
    End With

    With calcws
    Sheets("Calculations1").Activate
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol > 1 Then
    LastCol = LastCol + 1
    End If
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(1, LastCol) = "Incre_Disp_A_" & i
    Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = "Cumul_Disp_A_" & i
    End With

    With calcws
    Set Rng7 = Cells(2, LastCol)
    Debug.Print Rng7.Address
    Set Rng8 = Cells(LastRow, LastCol)
    Debug.Print Rng8.Address
    Set NewRng3 = .Range(Rng7.Address & ":" & Rng8.Address)
    Debug.Print NewRng3.Address
    NewRng3.Formula = "=NewRng1 - NewRng2"
    End With

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas of how to get the actual value to print on the Calculations1 sheet? Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please indent your loops, it makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NewRng3.Formula = "=NewRng1 - NewRng2"
```

should be

```
NewRng3.Formula = "=" & NewRng1.Address() & "-" & NewRng2.Address()
```